# R - Sum every two columns in a dataframe and paste results to new columns at the end

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of dynamic length, i.e. it get's longer everytime new variables are attached. In this case, I need to sum the values in every two columns `8:length(df)` and attach the results (the sum of every two columns) at the end of this dataframe. So what I want to automate for alle columns in question is this:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(sumAB = A + B)
```

Ideally, I would like to name these new columns based on a vector containing the intended `colnames`, which I already prepared. As I am fairly new to R, I could not get this running with for loops or the apply family. Every suggestion appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split.default` to split every two columns and then using `lapply` sum the values.

```
cols <- 8:ncol(df)
result <- cbind(df[1:8], sapply(split.default(df[cols], 
                     rep(1:length(cols), each = 2, length.out = length(cols))), 
                     rowSums, na.rm = TRUE))
result
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Any suggestions for renaming? The new columns are now named V1:V41 - I have a character value with 41 entries I want to paste to the column names.

Comment: you can do `colnames(result)[9:ncol(result)] <- character_value`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I also just found another solution, maybe to easy to think of it in the first place: `df <- rename_with(df, character_value)`